# How likely is it for a father to succeed his late son on the throne, while this son also has a younger brother?

Tags: politics, government

this is my first post on this forum. Please see the actual question in **bold** below, after the initial explanation and further information which is crucial to the question.

I have the following question about throne sucession with the following thee characters:

A: Former monarch, father of two, abdicated in favour of his eldest son (B).
B: Eldest son, who is now king. He dies a few years into his reign. He is childless. *The succession question takes place on the moment of his death*.
C: Younger son of father A, heir presumptive.

At the point of B's death, A and C are both alive. Both of A's children are legitimate and it takes place in 19th century Europe.

If I were to follow normal succession laws, the heir presumptive (younger son C) would become king. But, father A was in his time a really popular monarch, and for this question I would like to disregard the reason why he would abdicate in the first place.

**What I'm actually asking is: *How likely would it be for father A to be crowned king?***

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome. Please note that we are *not* forum but a Question -Answer website.

Comment: How exactly do I make my question more clear? It's right there after the initial explanation

Comment: I've made an edit if that helps

Comment: @FatMax1492 I think you can pretty much do whatever you want. There's three things in your favour. One is that succession is handled differently per culture. Two is that within a culture it can change over time. Three is that people do not 'play fair'. From simply being more powerful than the son to murder, intrigue, corruption, blackmail and bribery. The past is littered with dead royalty and weird successions.

Comment: The rules of succession of different countries are different, have always been different, and will always be different. And anyway, the rules can be waved. Unless the question refers to a real world country and a well-defined time in history, the only possible answer is that only the author of the story can know. A real-world historical example is King [Philip V of Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_V_of_Spain), who abdicated in 1724 in favor of his eldest son Louis I, and then, when Louis I died of smallpox, took back the throne although he also had a younger son, Ferdinand VI.

Comment: If you're asking about historical "normal succession laws", it would be off-topic (and you could ask this on [History SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/), *if* they allow hypotheticals), and if this is about a world you're building, those rules don't apply and you can make them up yourself.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm a bit unhappy with how you were treated, @FatMax1492. I apologize for that. Noting that our job per our [help/on-topic] is to help you develop an imaginary world of your own creation, what we can do is (as Alex did) point out a real-world example (if they exist, happens to in this case) that you can use to develop your imaginary world. It's worth noting that succession laws are hardly written in stone - wars were fought to change them, after all, when they were inconvenient. Thus, they can be what you need them to be.

Comment: Tsar Simeon of Bulgaria kind of did this. He was king until the Commies came in and occupied the country. He never abdicated but was exiled and "popular "referrendum"" abolished the monarchy. He has kids and was later elected Prime Minister of Bulgaria. Generally speaking, abdication pretty much puts paid to any attempt at returning to the throne. There is, e.g., no way Edward VIII would have ever come back to the British throne; but he did almost come back as a German stately king after the war.

Answer (score 2):

We are here building *fictional* worlds, informed by logic, science, history, precedent, and all that. So the answer is *"it depends on the traditions of your monarchy."* And with that, some people have voted to close as *unanswerable*. Since you are new here, I'll try an answer anyway.

Most monarchies these days are *constitutional* monarchies, where the crowned head of state gets to cut ribbons, and read speeches prepared by the elected head of government. I expect you are talking about a monarchy with real powers.

Monarchies might have had elaborate theoretical justifications, from the [divine right of kings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_right_of_kings) to the idea that the monarch [literally owns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feudalism) the country, and allows residents to live and work in return for paying rents. But in the end, the real purpose of monarchies was to **regulate power struggles** during a succession. If it is simply the strongest [warlord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlord) running things, then you get [other warlords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_of_the_Four_Emperors) trying to find out if they are stronger than the incumbent. A [widely accepted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_Sanction_of_1713) dynastic succession prevents this. Disputed succession leads to strife, possibly for generations as pretenders [claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Edward_Stuart) to be the rightful king. And who can say? The rules were changed before ... much better for the realm if the rules are clear.

So:

- In most societies, allowing an abdicated monarch to **reclaim** the throne is quite unacceptable, because it puts the princlple of clear succession into question. Once the monarch abdicates, he or she is out of consideration. If it was otherwise, could the heir of the heir of an abdicated monarch also claim the throne? Where does it end?
- For minor or unfit monarchs, there is the concept of a [regent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regent). Someone who holds all the powers of the monarch *in trust* for the real monarch, and/or the current and future heirs. This sounds much more plausible.
- But there were [elective monarchies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elective_monarchy), where some limited group (nobles? [very senior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince-elector) nobles?) would elect the king (from their own ranks? from the descendants of the [founder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succession_to_the_Saudi_Arabian_throne)?). In such a system, it might be thinkable for the former king to run again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a historical example of this happening in the inter-war period of the twentieth century. It did not go well, largely due to the personality of the individual involved.

[Carol II of Romania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carol_II_of_Romania), while crown prince, abdicated in favour of his son, later [Michael I of Romania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_I_of_Romania) and left the country. When Carol II's father died, Michael I inherited the throne as an infant, but the regent was ineffective, Carol II returned to Romania, claimed the throne and ruled 1930-40. He was eventually forced to abdicate again in 1940. He wanted to claim the throne *again* after WWII, but was not successful.

A fictional example will depend on the constitution and conventions of the state involved, as well as the personalities involved and the political situation at the time. There are no international rules for these things.